# Argue that in a planar graph on n nodes there is an independent set of at least n/8 nodes, each of degree at most 11.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am having troubles with this question. Seems non-trivial as I see it. The tightest lower-bound I could reach was "at least n/12" number of nodes in the independent set, with the assumption that all nodes have degree at most 11. Can someone help me with a line of reasoning?

Comment: I guess a planar graph has average degree < 6 by Euler so only half the vertiices can have higher degree than 11. Now by four color theorem , we can find a stable sets of at most n/4.  Does that get you some where?

Answer (score 3):

The above attempt is not the right approach. One can imagine a solution as follows.

We have that in a planar graph G, there are at least n/2 nodes with a degree at most 11. This can be proved using contradiction. Assume there are > n/2 nodes with degree >=12. Then, we have the sum of degrees for the nodes in the graph to be 6n. This contradicts the result that the sum of degrees in a planar graph is at most 6n-12.

Next, we let A to be a set of size n/2 with each degree at most 11. Let G' be the sub-graph induced by these nodes. Following the four colour theorem, we know that we can color sub-graph G' with 4 colours. We also know that the colour with the maximum number of nodes will have at least |A|/4 number of nodes by pigeon hole principle. Further, nodes of a single colour in a colouring scheme would be independent by definition. Hence, we have an independent set with at least n/8 nodes, each with degree at most 11.

Comment: In general, if we're proving $6$ where we want $4$ for planar graphs, or proving $12$ where we want $8$, or something similar, it's a good bet that whatever straightforward argument we used can be replaced by the four-color theorem - because straightforward arguments only get us the six-color theorem.